# What are some good thinking tools that a tester can use to generate ideas?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design

As a tester I want to generate more out of the box ideas, so that I can test all positive as well as negative test scenarios and find most critical defects before the product is released.

Are there any thinking/ideation tools, methods/techniques that might help me think better and generate ideas fast?

Comment: I can appreciate the problem you're facing, but how would you go about selecting a "correct" answer? I think this is a little too broad/opinion based for this site, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

1. I shared this more than once [37 Sources for Test Ideas](http://thetesteye.com/posters/TheTestEye_SourcesForTestIdeas.pdf)
2. Become a [Skeptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism), it will change your view of the product but also of life

Answer (score 3):

**Mindmaps**: I love to create a mindmap of what I am going to test, certainly if it is a larger or complex area. Read [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/are-mind-maps-useful-as-a-testing-tool) for how to use mindmaps as a testing tool.

For more example mindmaps with testing as subject have a look at: http://www.ministryoftesting.com/resources/mindmaps/