# How do I improve my Test Idea generation ability?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, functional

I have always tried to improve my test coverage as a black-box tester. Still, I believe that I need to improve my ability to generate practical and highly-usable ideas to test better so that I find serious bugs easily.

What are some models, theories, heuristics that have really helped you to find any kind of bug in any web-application. Kindly share some black-box testing heuristics for an enterprise web application.

Comment: IMHO better way than adding yet another partial answer would be to close this one and add a link  to most highly rated previous question/answer.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked many times before on this forum. So you should try to research a bit before adding this question.

Take a look at

- [Here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16140/what-are-some-good-thinking-tools-that-a-tester-can-use-to-generate-ideas?rq=1) where there is a list of good thinking tools and techniques mentioned for improving your practical thinking ability.
- You can start by reading the number of books mentioned [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing)
- You can also follow many of the points mentioned [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9577/how-to-become-a-more-creative-software-tester?rq=1)

However, as I have mentioned [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16298/what-material-can-help-a-tester-generate-more-and-better-ideas?rq=1), doing proper analysis and research, is the best tool for a tester, something which you seemed to have missed here (not a rant in any way).

Answer (score 1):

Try to **break** every functionality, just think how break every section this point is call test case and defiantly it will help you